# Order of cases in an enum that conforms to CaseIterable protocol in Swift?

Tags: swift, enums

Is the order of cases in an enum that conforms to `CaseIterable` protocol guaranteed to be the order in which it was declared ?

```
enum MyEnum: CaseIterable {
    case test
    case foo
    case bar
    case play
}

print(MyEnum.allCases)
```

will print:

`[MyEnum.test, MyEnum.foo, MyEnum.bar, MyEnum.play]`

I want to know if this order is guaranteed.

From this [blog](https://swiftrocks.com/how-caseiterable-works-internally-in-swift.html) we can see that the way swift compiler parses, the order is guaranteed. But I could not find any documentation that this behaviour is guaranteed and not subject to change.

P.S. This is not a case of XYZ problem. I just want to know about this particular behaviour in Swift.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, according to the documentation.

> [The synthesized allCases collection provides the cases in order of their declaration.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/caseiterable)

Comment: Ohh. I don't know how I missed it. Thanks.